# What is pointer pointing to when there's no element in that array's index?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

I created an array of

```
int A[5] = {2,4,6,8,10};
```

and made two pointers

```
int *p=A, *q=&A[5];
```

since there's only five elements in the array, as far as I understand in c++, when there's nothing it's supposed to be zero.

When I try to print out

```
cout<<"*p = "<<*p<<endl;
cout<<"*q = "<<*q<<endl;
```

I got this one instead

```
*p = 2
*q = 32766
```

I might be wrong about pointer **p**, it's pointing to the the first element by default.

But I don't understand why such a huge value is printed in pointer **q**, even though it's not even memory address in heap.

Can someone explain to me what's happening?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Dereferencing one past the end pointer to array type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52727045/dereferencing-one-past-the-end-pointer-to-array-type)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> As far as I understand in c++, when there's nothing it's supposed to be zero.

You've misunderstood.

> ```
> cout<<"*q = "<<*q<<endl;
> ```

Here you indirect through a pointer that points outside the bounds of the array, and attempt to access a non-existing element. The behaviour of the program is undefined.

> Can someone explain to me?

Behaviour of the program is undefined. The behaviour could be anything. This time you observed the output of `32766`. That is one possible behaviour among all behaviours that a program can have.

Undefined behaviour is to be avoided.

Comment: As for why it prints out some arbitrary number, the UB manifests as simply printing out whatever memory is at that location as if it was an integer.

Comment: @Justin To be more accurate: UB appeared to have manifest*ed* like that. There are no guarantees that it would manifest like that always.

Answer (score 2):

`A[5]` contains only 5 elements, so the only indexes that are valid are 0 to 4.

So while you can refer to the address of `A[5]`:

```
int *q = A + 5;  // fine
```

this address is not pointing to valid memory, and dereferencing this address invokes undefined behavior.

```
cout << *q; // ub
```

Also note that:

```
int *q = &A[5];  // ub
```

is also UB, because the right hand side becomes `&(A[5])`, but `A[5]` invokes UB straight away.

UB means anything can happen. In your case, some value got printed to the screen, but there's no guarantee of that happening.

Comment: "right hand side becomes &(A[5]), but A[5] invokes UB straight away." --> Hmm, I have [doubts](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47900466/2410359) about that.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but I think c has special wording to allow this, while c++ doesn't.

Comment: Fair consideration.